Вятский. Почему не вятцкий?
По правилам русского языка, если слово оканчивается на к-ч-ц, то к нему прибавляется суффикс -к-, а не -ск-.
Слово "вятский" образовано от слова "Вятка", основа которого оканчивается на к.
Значит, мы должны писать вятцкий, учтя чередование к-ц, а никак не вятский.
Почему же тогда зафиксировано в словаре совсем иное?

Татьяна Алексеевна, пожалуйста, приведите ссылку на источник, где упомянутое Вами правило образования суффиксов описано подробно, с примерами.

Образование слова «вятский» выглядит закономерным, подобно азия - азиат(ка) – азиатский или швеция - швед(ка) – шведский.

Вопрос закономерный: выбор суффиксов СК/К в прилагательных — весьма трудная тема.
ТЕОРИЯ
Общее правило
  1. Суффикс СК используется для образования относительных 
  прилагательных от существительных, при этом надо 
  учитывать: если  основа заканчивается на з у б н ы е 
  согласные Д, Т, З, С , то на стыке морфем происходят 
  различные ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ звука.

  2. Суффикс К может являться в а р и а н т о м суффикса СК 
  при образовании относительных прилагательных от 
  существительных в двух случаях: если основа заканчивается 
  на Ц: молодец – молодецкий; если в основе происходит ч е р 
  е д о в а н и е звуков К, Ч на Ц: бедняк – бедняцкий, 
  кулак – кулацкий, мужик – мужицкий, ткач – ткацкий.

Для географических названий:
  1. В большинстве случаев в географических и других 
  названиях действуют те же правила употребления суффиксов 
  СК и К, а именно:
  суффикс относительных прилагательных СК является основным 
  вариантом: швед – шведский, киргиз – киргизский, Ташкент – 
  ташкентский, тунгус – тунгусский, черкес – черкесский.

  2. Суффикс относительных прилагательных К пишется после Ц, 
  а также при чередовании К на Ц:  немец – немецкий – основа 
  на Ц, суффикс К; калмык – калмыцкий, казак – казацкий.
  

В то же время существуют частные особенности выбора суффиксов. При выборе суффиксов для прилагательных, образованных от географических названий, в том числе иноязычных, существуют две т е н д е н ц и и. С одной стороны, слово должно вписываться в фонетическую систему языка, с другой стороны – требуется обеспечить м и н и м а л ь н о е искажение исходного названия.
Соответственно возможно: (1) использование суффикса СК, наряду с суффиксом К для основ на Ц, а также К и Ч; (2) различные варианты наложения суффикса СК на основу и усечение основы.
РЕШЕНИЕ
Вятка — вятк/ск/ий?
Нет, сочетание ТКСК неудобно для произношения, поэтому усекаем основу на К: вят/ск/ий.
Другими словами, фонетические проблемы лежат в основе этого правила, а для географических названий  есть свои особенности.
